# How to use fork join in recursion (Java) while using matrix multiplication divide and conquer?

Tags: java, join, matrix, fork, multiplication

Please add code for fork(), join() wherever it can be added.
I need to parallelise this matrix multiplication.

The code is given below

```
public static long[][] dc(long[][] M1, long[][] M2, int n)
{

    long[][] M = new long[n][n];

    if (n == 1)
      M[0][0] = M1[0][0] * M2[0][0];
    else 
    {
      int size= n/2;
      long[][] A11 = new long[n/2][n/2];
      long[][] A12 = new long[n/2][n/2];
      long[][] A21 = new long[n/2][n/2];
      long[][] A22 = new long[n/2][n/2];
      long[][] B11 = new long[n/2][n/2];
      long[][] B12 = new long[n/2][n/2];
      long[][] B21 = new long[n/2][n/2];
      long[][] B22 = new long[n/2][n/2];

        copy1(A11,M1,0,0,size);
        copy1(A12,M1,0,(n/2),size);
        copy1(A21,M1,(n/2),0,size);
        copy1(A22,M1,(n/2),(n/2),size);
        copy1(B11,M2,0,0,size);
        copy1(B12,M2,0,(n/2),size);
        copy1(B21,M2,(n/2),0,size);
        copy1(B22,M2,(n/2),(n/2),size);

      long[][] C11 = add( dc(A11, B11,size), dc(A12, B21,size) ,size);//need to fork
      long[][] C12 = add( dc(A11, B12,size), dc(A12, B22,size) ,size);//need to fork
      long[][] C21 = add( dc(A21, B11,size), dc(A22, B21,size) ,size);//need to fork
      long[][] C22 = add( dc(A21, A12,size), dc(A22, B22,size) ,size);//need to fork

        copy2(M,C11,0,0,size);
        copy2(M,C12,0,(n/2),size);
        copy2(M,C21,(n/2),0,size);
        copy2(M,C22,(n/2),(n/2),size);
    }
    return M;
}
```

Should I use java or fork(), exec(), pthread() ?

Edit:

Here is my parallelised code. It does not work for greater than N=32
I get an exception - Java.outofmemory Exception

```
public static long[][] dc(long[][] M1, long[][] M2, int n)
{
    long[][] M=new long[n][n];
    if (n == 1)
      M[0][0] = M1[0][0] * M2[0][0];
    else 
    {

      int size= n/2;
      long[][] A11 = new long[n/2][n/2];
      long[][] A12 = new long[n/2][n/2];
      long[][] A21 = new long[n/2][n/2];
      long[][] A22 = new long[n/2][n/2];
      long[][] B11 = new long[n/2][n/2];
      long[][] B12 = new long[n/2][n/2];
      long[][] B21 = new long[n/2][n/2];
      long[][] B22 = new long[n/2][n/2];


        copy1(A11,M1,0,0,size);
        copy1(A12,M1,0,(n/2),size);
        copy1(A21,M1,(n/2),0,size);
        copy1(A22,M1,(n/2),(n/2),size);
        copy1(B11,M2,0,0,size);
        copy1(B12,M2,0,(n/2),size);
        copy1(B21,M2,(n/2),0,size);
        copy1(B22,M2,(n/2),(n/2),size);



     class T1 extends Thread
     {
        private long[][] p1;
        public void run()
        {
            p1=dc(A11,B11,size);
            //System.out.println("P1");
            //disp(p1);
        }
     };
     class T2 extends Thread
     {
        private long[][] p2;
        public void run()
        {
            p2=dc(A12,B21,size);
            //System.out.println("P2");
            //disp(p2);
        }
     };
     class T3 extends Thread
     {
        private long[][] p3;
        public void run()
        {
            p3=dc(A11,B12,size);
            //System.out.println("P3");
            //disp(p3);
        }
     };
     class T4 extends Thread
     {
        private long[][] p4;
        public void run()
        {
            p4=dc(A12,B22,size);
            //System.out.println("P4");
            //disp(p4);
        }
     };
     class T5 extends Thread
     {
        private long[][] p5;
        public void run()
        {
            p5=dc(A21,B11,size);
            //System.out.println("P5");
            //disp(p5);
        }
     };
     class T6 extends Thread
     {
        private long[][] p6;
        public void run()
        {
            p6=dc(A22,B21,size);
            //System.out.println("P6");
            //disp(p6);
        }
     };
     class T7 extends Thread
     {
        private long[][] p7;
        public void run()
        {
            p7=dc(A21,B12,size);
            //System.out.println("P7");
            //disp(p7);
        }
     };
     class T8 extends Thread
     {
        private long[][] p8;
        public void run()
        {
            p8=dc(A22,B22,size);
            //System.out.println("P8");
            //disp(p8);
        }
     };

     T1 t1=new T1(); T2 t2=new T2(); T3 t3=new T3(); T4 t4=new T4();
     T5 t5=new T5(); T6 t6=new T6(); T7 t7=new T7(); T8 t8=new T8();
     t1.start();t2.start();t3.start();t4.start();t5.start();t6.start();t7.start();t8.start();
     try 
     {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();
        t5.join();
        t6.join();
        t7.join();
        t8.join();
        //System.out.println("Threads completed");
        //disp(t1.p1);
     } 
     catch (InterruptedException e) 
     {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Exception occured");

     }
     long[][] C11=add(t1.p1,t2.p2,size);
     long[][] C12=add(t3.p3,t4.p4,size);
     long[][] C21=add(t5.p5,t6.p6,size);
     long[][] C22=add(t7.p7,t8.p8,size);

        copy2(M,C11,0,0,size);
        copy2(M,C12,0,(n/2),size);
        copy2(M,C21,(n/2),0,size);
        copy2(M,C22,(n/2),(n/2),size);
    }
    return M;
}

public static long[][] add(long[][] M1, long[][] M2, int size)
{
    long[][] M=new long[size][size];    
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            M[i][j]=M1[i][j]+M2[i][j];
        }
    }
    //System.out.println("Add method");
    return M;

}
```

Could you please let me know how to make threads work for large inputs?
This code is actually slower than my code without threads. SO threads are actually not of any use at all. 
Cold you please correct the code and let me know how to parallelise it effectively so that its faster than the code without parallelisation?

Thanks!

Comment: fork all of the child calls to dc, then join the two you need at each add.

Comment: Show us how you tried to parallelize it yourself.